# int i in a for loop vs not

Tags: c

Why would the following not work when i is defined in the for loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int N;
long long int H() {

    long long int ans=0;
    int i, lt;

    if(N <= 0)
        return 0;

    for(i=1, lt=sqrt(N); i<=lt; i+=1) /* if i=1 is replaced by int i=1 => garbage */
        ans+=(N/i);

    ans = 2*ans-(lt*lt);
    return ans;

}
int main() {

    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("%lld\n",H());

    return 0;
}
```

output when it's defined at the top

```
Input: 8
Output: 20
```

output when it's defined in the for loop `/* for (int i=1 ..) */`

```
Input: 8
Output: 1243068212
```

I see that I get a warning `lt is initialized when used here`, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write this:

```
int lt;
for (int i=1, lt=sqrt(N); ...)
```

That defines **two** new inner variables named `i` and `lt`; in particular, the new `lt` variable *shadows* the outer one, making it temporarily inaccessible within the inner scope.  So, the outer `lt` variable never gets initialized, and when you compute `ans = 2*ans-(lt*lt)`, it's using that uninitialized value to compute the result.

Comment: +1.  At first blush, the problem might appear to be the C++ style "int i".  But in fact, it's the expression `int i=1, lt=sqrt(N)`, which creates two *NEW* variables "i", *AND* "lt".

Comment: @paulsm4: It is not an "expression". It is a declaration.

Comment: That declaration *IS* an expression.  "Expressions are sequences of operators and operands that are used for one or more of these purposes."

Comment: @paulsm4: Huh??? No. A declaration is certainly *not* an expression. What that "Expressions are sequences of operators..." quote is supposed to mean here is not clear to me. And if you think that `,` in a sequence of declarators is a "comma operator", you still have a lot to learn. One more time: a declaration is *not* an expression.

Answer (score 0):

One good pattern to look for when starting coding in C is variables with values WAY out of bounds of what they should be.

So in your case you were expecting `20` and instead got `1243068212`, this implies that the variable was not initiated properly and thus it's value is an undefined piece of memory (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Here's a good article on initialization - http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html